# How to paint over an emission shader with principled shader?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I am trying to create a light source that has some dirt/grime on it. I am using an emissive material for the light and a principled shader for the dirt. I am trying to texture paint over the emission shader but my texture paint won't show up with my current node setup. Does anyone have any advice?[image: Node Setup][image: Texture Paint]

Comment: It's showing up, but it's wrong, and it's being drowned out by your emission.  Don't add shader.  Mix shader instead.  What fac?  Where there's grime, mix to Principled; where there's not, mix to Emission.  How to define where there's grime?  Maybe an image texture would be a good idea, plug it into mix shader fac, but you can define it any number of ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to mix the texture paint with the emission shader, I simply plugged the image texture directly into the fac of the mix shader and used an invert node.
[image: Light]
[image: Node]